# How can I remove row name from my table in R?

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
day = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03","2019-01-04") 
case = c(3,2,8,11) 
rbind(day, case) 
data = data.frame(rbind(day, case)) 
row.names(data) = colnames (data) = NULL 
row.names(data)=NULL 
print(data,row.names = F)
```

The output is this:

```
2019-01-01   2019-01-02   2019-01-03   2019-01-04

    3            2            8            11
```

but If I use

```
print(data)
```

I have this:

```
1 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-04

2      3          2          8         11
```

My question: How can I assign a variable name to this output from "print(data)" to make it usable for my work, without row name and without column name which I need. Thanks

Comment: You should post reproducible code.  We don't have `epid` or `epid.count`.

Comment: looks like your output is already an object `epid_new`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I used wrong variables, I have corrected it

Comment: Anyone with solution should kindly help, I'm preparing an analysis on epidemiology survey

Comment: is it possible to assign a variable name for  "print(data,row.names = F) ".  I want to use the output for further analysis, for example can I call it  "data_new"?

Comment: Probably you're looking for `setNames(case, day)`.

Comment: I don't want 1 and 2 rownames in my new data

Answer (score 1):

In R, objects of class `data.frame` must have row names. Unfortunately, there's no way around it.

When you try to remove the `rownames`, the system simply puts them back. If you try to remove them at a low level, it breaks the object:

```
attr(data,"row.names") <- NULL
data
#NULL
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

You could convert your `data` object to class `matrix`, but in R, matrices can only have *one* type of data. So (in a hypothetical example) if you had columns with both numeric type data and character type data, the numeric data would have to be converted to character:

```
as.matrix(data)
#     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
#[1,] "2019-01-01" "2019-01-02" "2019-01-03" "2019-01-04"
#[2,] "3"          "2"          "8"          "11"
```

Overall, I don't think you should worry about the row names and just continue with your analysis.

Comment: I'm working on reproduction number of a disease using Ro package in R. The data used in the example  ```data (Gernany.1918)```    has neither row nor column names. I have not been able to do the analysis because my data does not have the same format prescribed for such data

Comment: The object `Germany.1918` from package `R0` is class numeric vector with names that are the date. To do the same with your data, you could do `names(case) <- day`.

Comment: ```names(case) <- day ```  really helps

Answer (score 0):

I have found an indirect way using a capture of the print:

```
temp <- paste0(capture.output(
                print(data, row.names=FALSE)
               ),collapse="\n") 
cat(temp, "\n")
```

which shows

```
        X1         X2         X3         X4
2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-04
         3          2          8         11>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove row names like this:

```
newdata = data.frame(data, row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry to down vote but I'm afraid this does not work. If you run this code and then run `names(attributes(newdata))`, it will return `"names"     "class"     "row.names"`, i.e. the data still has a row names attribute.

Comment: Note that `rownames(data) <- NULL` works very well. This answer inspired this observation, so I upvote